# Count active processes in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm looking for 2 Ubuntu terminal commands that will:

1. Show **currently running** processes (or tasks).
2. Count how many **currently running** processes (or tasks) there are.

I am windows user and I'm not sure if it's named tasks or processes, but I'm looking for the same thing that's displayed when I open windows task manager.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy using the `ps` utility. That will return a list of

- PID: Process identification number.
- TTY: The type of terminal the process is running on.
- TIME: Total amount of CPU usage.
- CMD: The name of the command that started the process.

You can also combine/pipe it with `wc` to count the lines produced by it, hence counting the number of processes, like this:

```
$ ps -e | wc -l
```

You can find more info [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/list-processes-linux#:%7E:text=To%20list%20currently%20running%20processes,command%20to%20identify%20individual%20processes.) and [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-count-how-many-processes-are-running-in-linux/).